# Python Multiprocessing appending list

Tags: python, variables, multiprocessing, shared

Have a quick question about a shared variable between multiple processes using Multiprocessing.Pool().

Will I run in to any issues if I am updating a global list from within multiple processes? I.e. if two of the processes were to try to update the list at the same time.

I have seen documentation about using a Lock for similar things but I was wondering if it was necessary.

EDIT:

The way I am sharing this variable is by using a global variable in my callback function,
'successes' in which i append all of the successful actions to after the target function has completed:

```
TOTAL_SUCCESSES = []

def func(inputs):
    successes = []

    for input in inputs:
        result = #something with return code
        if result == 0:
            successes.append(input)
    return successes

def callback(successes):
    global TOTAL_SUCCESSES

    for entry in successes:
        TOTAL_SUCCESSES.append(entry)

def main():     
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for entry in myInputs:
         pool.apply_async(func, args=(entry,),callback=callback)
```

Apologize for any syntax errors, wrote this up quickly but the program is working just wondering if I add the shared variable if I will have issues.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you sharing the list?  If you are passing a simple list in directly, each process will get a local copy of the list.  Are you using a queue?  A multiprocessing.Array?

Comment: You'll glean a great deal by reading through the multiprocessing examples: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#examples, but until you have some sample code for your implementation we can't tell you what pitfalls you might encounter.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the responses, edited with some code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With your current code, you're not actually sharing `CURRENT_SUCCESSES` between processes. `callback` is executed in the main process, in a result handling thread. There is only one result handling thread, so each `callback` will be run one at a time, not concurrently. So your code as written is process/thread safe.

However, you are forgetting to return `successes` from `func`, which you'll want to fix.

**Edit:**

Also, this could be much more succinctly written using `map`:

```
def func(inputs):
    successes = []

    for input in inputs:
        result = #something with return code
        if result == 0:
            successes.append(input)
    return successes

def main():     
    pool = mp.Pool()
    total_successes = pool.map(func, myInputs) # Returns a list of lists
    # Flatten the list of lists
    total_successes = [ent for sublist in total_successes for ent in sublist]
```

Comment: yup, sorry I am returning it (obviously). Thanks for the info! And yeah that makes perfect sense, I should have realized that.

Comment: Side note - Is there a more appropriate way to be doing this or is this acceptable?