# How to share dictionary between threads using multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm trying to share a dictionary between threads of multiprocessing.Pool. However, I'm failed with current implementation. Test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing

success_map = {"1": []}

def run_(input):
    global success_map
    successes = success_map.get(input);
    successes.append(0)
    print success_map

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(run_, ["1"])
pool.close()
pool.join()
print success_map
```

The output is

```
{'1': [0]}
{'1': []}
```

It looks to me that worker(s) of multiprocessing.Pool() create copies of dictionary; that's why I can't see update when processing is finished. Am I right?

Note:

1. I know it's possible to return value from `run_` function and get collected list as a result of `pool.map(run_, ["1"])`, but need to use global variable for current task
2. I'm aware of possible dataraces
3. I've read somewhere that `global` statement isn't needed in that case but example works the same way without it
4. I've got the same result passing `[["1", success_map]]` to `pool.map`; without usage of global variable

Is it possible to share `success_map` between threads in this example?

Related, but not an answer: [Python Multiprocessing appending list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411673/python-multiprocessing-appending-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiprocessing uses separate *processes*, not *threads*. These processes do not share all memory like threads do.

To [share data](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) between processes you could use e.g. `multiprocessing.Value` or `multiprocessing.Array`. But be aware that in some cicrumstances you'll [need an extra Lock](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing).

Using a `Manager` object you can share most data types (it must be pickle-able, I think). And it's slower that shared memory.

Or you could create a `multiprocessing.Pipe` to exchange data between processes.

---

**Notes**:

1. The multiprocessing module *does* use threads internally for 
   housekeeping.
2. In general it is better to avoid sending large pieces of data between processes.